# How to parse this JSON with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to read the JSON string that is inside the `<pre>` element here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process?input=hello%20world&outputFormat=json

If I copy-paste the string with the mouse, I can `JSON.parse()` it. But if I read it programmatically, I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
var request = require('request'); // to make POST requests
var Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities; // to decode the json string (i.e. get rid of nbsp and quot's)
var fs = require('fs')
// Set the headers
var headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    form: {
        'input': 'hello world',
        'outputFormat': 'json'
    }
}

// Start the request
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log("body: " + body)
        let cheerio = require('cheerio')
        let $ = cheerio.load(body)
        var inside = $('pre').text();
        inside = Entities.decode(inside.toString());
        //console.log("inside "+ inside);
        var obj = JSON.parse(inside);
        console.log(obj);
    }
})
```

But I get the following error:

```
undefined:2
  "sentences": [
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

And here is an excerpt from the output of the link, i.e. what I want to parse into `obj`:

```
{
&nbsp;&nbsp;&quot;sentences&quot;: [
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&quot;index&quot;: &quot;0&quot;,
...
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;}
&nbsp;&nbsp;]
}
```

How can I `JSON.parse()` such a string?

Thanks,

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, I already tried that, it's included in my code. But I'm still failing to parse it correctly.

Comment: what does the decoded string look like? `JSON.parse` shouldn't care about whitespace...

Comment: It looks like a regular string when I print on the console. But in the very beginning, the space before `{` is diagnosed as an unexpected token.

Comment: try `trim`ing the string prior to parsing to remove the leading whitespace. It shouldn't matter, but worth trying since the error is pointing you to that spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final Answer**

Both the output and the error you presented pointed at a problem to parse a space character right after the opening JSON bracket.
I suggest you remove all white spaces, that are not within quotes.

As follows:

`var obj = JSON.parse(str.replace(/(\s+?(?={))|(^\s+)|(\r|\n)|((?=[\[:,])\s+)/gm,''));`

**Original Answer**

I suggest you remove all white spaces.

So, `var obj = JSON.parse(inside.replace(/\s/g,''));` should work

Here is a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/3bjyv3d9/)

EDIT

Better: `var obj = JSON.parse(str.replace(/(\s+?(?={))|(^\s+)|(\r|\n)|((?=[\[:,])\s+)/gm,''));` will leave spaces inside quotes as they are, since "parse" has spaces in its value

Comment: This will replace **all** whitespace... including those in string values in the json.

Comment: I tried before with `inside = inside.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");`, which didn't work. However, this works! In this case, it looks like removing spaces are fine, since every element is a word which does not contain any space. So, thanks.. :)

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for your comment. edited my answer.

Comment: @remdevtec indeed, +1 to you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is all of those `&nbsp;`s.  Those represent a non-breaking space character, `U+00A0`.  Unfortunately, `JSON.parse` (correctly) chokes on those characters because the JSON spec, [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2), only treats regular spaces (`U+0020`), tabs, and line breaks as whitespace.

You could do the hacky thing, which is to replace every `U+00A0` with `U+0020`, but that would also affect non-breaking spaces inside of strings, which is not ideal.

The best way to handle input data like this would be to use a JSON parsing library that is more tolerant of other kinds of whitespace characters.

---

Why aren't you [running your own copy of CoreNLP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stanford-corenlp)?  I imagine they don't want you scraping their server.

Comment: OMG, I didn't know they made a Node.js wrapper! Thank you so much!